# Segmentation fault during GC in python 2.7.17

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, garbage-collection

Runtime: 2.7.17
Docker base image: python:2.7.17-slim-buster

Python application crashes intermittently with following stacktrace.
Using gdb to find the backtrace. The program crashes at [Modules/gcmodule.c#L332](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.17/Modules/gcmodule.c#L332)

This happens only in our production environment and is very difficult to replicate locally.

Can someone share what could be the root cause for this?

There does not seem to be any Github issues or past stack overflow questions related to this.

**UPDATE**

Python's crash trace.

Version of pymongo: 3.11.2

```
error Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault
Thread 0x00007f057553e700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/optimizely/config_manager.py", line 360 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 774 in __bootstrap
Thread 0x00007f057727f700 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340 in wait
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168 in get
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/transport/threaded.py", line 139 in _target
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 774 in __bootstrap
Thread 0x00007f05d51f1700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 140 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 774 in __bootstrap
Thread 0x00007f05d65f3700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 140 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 774 in __bootstrap
Thread 0x00007f05d6ff4700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 140 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 774 in __bootstrap
Friday, Mar 19th 2021, 5:12am
Thread 0x00007f05da8f8700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 140 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 774 in __bootstrap
Thread 0x00007f05d3aed700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 140 in _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801 in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 774 in __bootstrap
Current thread 0x00007f05f8cbf740 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17 in __enter__
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1247 in _get_socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17 in __enter__
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1309 in _slaveok_for_server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17 in __enter__
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1465 in _retryable_read
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1372 in _run_operation_with_response
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1001 in __send_message
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1124 in _refresh
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1207 in next
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 647 in __getitem__
```

gdb backtrace output

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  update_refs (containers=0x7feeca074120 <generations>) at Modules/gcmodule.c:332
332     Modules/gcmodule.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7feec9af6740 (LWP 1))]
(gdb) where
#0  update_refs (containers=0x7feeca074120 <generations>) at Modules/gcmodule.c:332
#1  collect (generation=0) at Modules/gcmodule.c:921
#2  0x00007feec9f95a2d in collect_generations () at Modules/gcmodule.c:1047
#3  _PyObject_GC_Malloc (basicsize=basicsize@entry=40) at Modules/gcmodule.c:1511
#4  0x00007feec9f4fbc0 in PyType_GenericAlloc (type=0x7feeca04e420 <_PyExc_AttributeError>, nitems=0) at Objects/typeobject.c:781
#5  0x00007feec9f1ccd9 in BaseException_new (type=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, kwds=<optimized out>) at Objects/exceptions.c:34
#6  0x00007feec9f503e5 in type_call (type=type@entry=0x7feeca04e420 <_PyExc_AttributeError>, args=args@entry=0x7fee2d128490, kwds=kwds@entry=0x0) at Objects/typeobject.c:749
#7  0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feeca04e420 <_PyExc_AttributeError>, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2d128490, kw=kw@entry=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#8  0x00007feec9f752e0 in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords (func=func@entry=0x7feeca04e420 <_PyExc_AttributeError>, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2d128490, kw=kw@entry=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:4245
#9  0x00007feec9f7e532 in PyErr_NormalizeException (exc=0x7ffcb17ac068, val=val@entry=0x7ffcb17ac070, tb=tb@entry=0x7ffcb17ac078) at Python/errors.c:192
#10 0x00007feec9f724ae in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3275
#11 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feec790b6b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7fee302cf5b8, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=kws@entry=0x0, kwcount=0,
    defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#12 0x00007feec9f21baa in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feec78bd1d0, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee302cf5a0, kw=kw@entry=0x0) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
#13 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feec78bd1d0, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee302cf5a0, kw=kw@entry=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#14 0x00007feec9f172ce in instancemethod_call (func=0x7feec78bd1d0, func@entry=0x7fee3049c500, arg=0x7fee302cf5a0, arg@entry=0x7fee30b0c7d0, kw=kw@entry=0x0) at Objects/classobject.c:2600
#15 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7fee3049c500, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee30b0c7d0, kw=kw@entry=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#16 0x00007feec9f53564 in call_method (o=<optimized out>, name=<optimized out>, nameobj=0x7feeca082188 <setattr_str>, format=0x7feec9fe4fa8 "(OO)") at Objects/typeobject.c:1283
#17 0x00007feec9fb7e6f in slot_tp_setattro (self=<optimized out>, name=<optimized out>, value=<optimized out>) at Objects/typeobject.c:5717
#18 0x00007feec9f3a398 in PyObject_SetAttr (v=v@entry=0x7fee45f48a50, name=name@entry=0x7feec79058b0, value=value@entry=0x7feeca044ac0 <_Py_ZeroStruct>) at Objects/object.c:1252
#19 0x00007feec9f6da45 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:2269
#20 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feec78fb0b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7fee2d128328, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=4,
    defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#21 0x00007feec9f21c67 in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feec78bb1d0, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2d128310, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee2fc36cb0) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
#22 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feec78bb1d0, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2d128310, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee2fc36cb0) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#23 0x00007feec9f73094 in ext_do_call (nk=0, na=1, flags=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ac900, func=0x7feec78bb1d0) at Python/ceval.c:4690
#24 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3052
#25 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feec9611db0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7fee2ebeb228, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=4,
    defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#26 0x00007feec9f21c67 in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feec766d4d0, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2ebeb210, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee2fc2dcb0) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
#27 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feec766d4d0, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2ebeb210, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee2fc2dcb0) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#28 0x00007feec9f172ce in instancemethod_call (func=0x7feec766d4d0, func@entry=0x7fee3049c730, arg=0x7fee2ebeb210, arg@entry=0x7feec9ab6050, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee2fc2dcb0) at Objects/classobject.c:2600
#29 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7fee3049c730, arg=arg@entry=0x7feec9ab6050, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee2fc2dcb0) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#30 0x00007feec9f526a2 in slot_tp_init (self=self@entry=0x7fee45f48a50, args=args@entry=0x7feec9ab6050, kwds=kwds@entry=0x7fee2fc2dcb0) at Objects/typeobject.c:5869
#31 0x00007feec9f50464 in type_call (type=<optimized out>, type@entry=0x55820a476250, args=args@entry=0x7feec9ab6050, kwds=kwds@entry=0x7fee2fc2dcb0) at Objects/typeobject.c:763
#32 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x55820a476250, arg=arg@entry=0x7feec9ab6050, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee2fc2dcb0) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#33 0x00007feec9f6d2dd in do_call (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ace68, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4593
#34 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ace68) at Python/ceval.c:4398
#35 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#36 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feeb4e207b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7fee302e26f8, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=kws@entry=0x0, kwcount=0,
    defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#37 0x00007feec9f21baa in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb9531a50, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee302e26e0, kw=kw@entry=0x0) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
#38 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb9531a50, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee302e26e0, kw=kw@entry=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#39 0x00007feec9f172ce in instancemethod_call (func=0x7feeb9531a50, func@entry=0x7fee332c61e0, arg=0x7fee302e26e0, arg@entry=0x7fee45f1b410, kw=kw@entry=0x0) at Objects/classobject.c:2600
#40 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7fee332c61e0, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee45f1b410, kw=kw@entry=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#41 0x00007feec9fb6562 in call_maybe (o=<optimized out>, name=<optimized out>, nameobj=<optimized out>, format=0x7feec9fe4f79 "(O)", format=0x7feec9fe4f79 "(O)") at Objects/typeobject.c:1323
#42 0x00007feec9fb646d in slot_nb_add (self=0x7fee45f71cd0, other=0x7fee4180ae10) at Objects/typeobject.c:5291
#43 0x00007feec9f0e178 in binary_op1 (op_slot=0, w=<optimized out>, v=<optimized out>) at Objects/abstract.c:945
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
#44 PyNumber_Add (v=0x7fee45f71cd0, w=w@entry=0x7fee4180ae10) at Objects/abstract.c:1185
#45 0x00007feec9ee69dc in builtin_sum (self=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at Python/bltinmodule.c:2446
#46 0x00007feec9f6cbc0 in call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ad508) at Python/ceval.c:4376
#47 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#48 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feeb4e2df30, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7fee2a255d28, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=2,
    defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#49 0x00007feec9f21c67 in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb953c750, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2a255d10, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee302c6b90) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
#50 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=0x7feeb953c750, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2a255d10, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee302c6b90) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#51 0x00007feec981b8b0 in partial_call (pto=pto@entry=0x7fee3048f650, args=args@entry=0x7fee2a255d10, kw=kw@entry=0x0) at /usr/src/python/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c:198
#52 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7fee3048f650, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2a255d10, kw=kw@entry=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#53 0x00007feec9f6d2dd in do_call (nk=<optimized out>, na=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ad7d8, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4593
#54 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ad7d8) at Python/ceval.c:4398
#55 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#56 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feeb4cb8730, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=1,
    defs=0x7feeb4cc7a28, defcount=5, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#57 0x00007feec9f6ce98 in fast_function (nk=1, na=6, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ad9a8, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4471
#58 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ad9a8) at Python/ceval.c:4396
#59 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#60 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feeb4cb81b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7feec9ab6068, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=8,
    defs=0x7feeb4cc79c8, defcount=4, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#61 0x00007feec9f21c67 in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb4ccab50, arg=arg@entry=0x7feec9ab6050, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee33957050) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
#62 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb4ccab50, arg=arg@entry=0x7feec9ab6050, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee33957050) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#63 0x00007feec9f73094 in ext_do_call (nk=0, na=0, flags=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17adc20, func=0x7feeb4ccab50) at Python/ceval.c:4690
#64 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3052
#65 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feec98a03b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7feec9ab6068, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=8,
    defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x7feeb4cc96d0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#66 0x00007feec9f21c67 in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb4ccabd0, arg=arg@entry=0x7feec9ab6050, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee3396a5f0) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
#67 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb4ccabd0, arg=arg@entry=0x7feec9ab6050, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee3396a5f0) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#68 0x00007feec9f73094 in ext_do_call (nk=1, na=0, flags=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ade90, func=0x7feeb4ccabd0) at Python/ceval.c:4690
#69 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3052
#70 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feeb45b9c30, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0, defs=0x0,
    defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#71 0x00007feec9f7229d in fast_function (nk=0, na=4, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ae058, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4471
#72 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ae058) at Python/ceval.c:4396
#73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#74 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feeb45b9bb0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0,
    defs=0x7feeb949f428, defcount=1, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#75 0x00007feec9f6ce98 in fast_function (nk=0, na=4, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ae228, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4471
#76 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ae228) at Python/ceval.c:4396
#77 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#78 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feeb45b9ab0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0,
    defs=0x7feeb949f3a8, defcount=1, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#79 0x00007feec9f6ce98 in fast_function (nk=0, na=4, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ae3f8, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4471
#80 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ae3f8) at Python/ceval.c:4396
#81 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#82 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feeb45b99b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7fee2c4a4ec8, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=1,
    defs=0x7feeb94986a8, defcount=2, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#83 0x00007feec9f21c67 in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb94a1450, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2c4a4eb0, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee302d3290) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
#84 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb94a1450, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2c4a4eb0, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee302d3290) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#85 0x00007feec9f73094 in ext_do_call (nk=0, na=0, flags=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ae670, func=0x7feeb94a1450) at Python/ceval.c:4690
#86 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3052
#87 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feebf0b0e30, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7fee302cc248, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=1,
    defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x7feeb94924b0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#88 0x00007feec9f21c67 in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb94a14d0, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee302cc230, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee3396c170) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
#89 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb94a14d0, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee302cc230, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee3396c170) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#90 0x00007feec9f73094 in ext_do_call (nk=0, na=0, flags=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17ae8e0, func=0x7feeb94a14d0) at Python/ceval.c:4690
#91 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3052
#92 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feec98a01b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=1, defs=0x0,
    defcount=0, closure=0x7feeb94986e0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#93 0x00007feec9f7229d in fast_function (nk=1, na=2, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17aeaa8, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4471
#94 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17aeaa8) at Python/ceval.c:4396
#95 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#96 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feeb4e3ccb0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7fee2a24f668, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=5,
    defs=0x7feeb954d9e8, defcount=9, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#97 0x00007feec9f21c67 in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb954d950, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2a24f650, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee330c7050) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
#98 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb954d950, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2a24f650, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee330c7050) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#99 0x00007feec9f73094 in ext_do_call (nk=0, na=0, flags=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17aed20, func=0x7feeb954d950) at Python/ceval.c:4690
#100 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3052
#101 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feebf0b0e30, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7fee33ccb8a8, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=5,
    defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x7feeb95a7680) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#102 0x00007feec9f21c67 in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb954da50, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee33ccb890, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee2fd31050) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
#103 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb954da50, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee33ccb890, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee2fd31050) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#104 0x00007feec9f73094 in ext_do_call (nk=0, na=0, flags=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17aef90, func=0x7feeb954da50) at Python/ceval.c:4690
#105 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3052
#106 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feec98a01b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=6, defs=0x0,
    defcount=0, closure=0x7feeb954b640) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#107 0x00007feec9f7229d in fast_function (nk=6, na=4, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17af158, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4471
#108 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17af158) at Python/ceval.c:4396
#109 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#110 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feeb6d0e130, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7fee2ffeb0e8, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=2,
    defs=0x7feeb9453668, defcount=8, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#111 0x00007feec9f21c67 in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb94535d0, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2ffeb0d0, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee2e04cb90) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
#112 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb94535d0, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2ffeb0d0, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee2e04cb90) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#113 0x00007feec9f73094 in ext_do_call (nk=0, na=0, flags=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17af3d0, func=0x7feeb94535d0) at Python/ceval.c:4690
#114 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3052
#115 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feebf0b0e30, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=2, defs=0x0,
    defcount=0, closure=0x7feeb94550c0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#116 0x00007feec9f7229d in fast_function (nk=2, na=1, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17af598, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4471
#117 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17af598) at Python/ceval.c:4396
#118 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#119 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feea6124cb0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7fee41c58428, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=1,
    defs=0x7feea5ea1468, defcount=1, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#120 0x00007feec9f21c67 in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feea5feef50, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee41c58410, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee2e068710) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
#121 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feea5feef50, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee41c58410, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee2e068710) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#122 0x00007feec9f73094 in ext_do_call (nk=0, na=0, flags=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17af810, func=0x7feea5feef50) at Python/ceval.c:4690
#123 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3052
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--c
#124 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feec0f291b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7fee2dc27968, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#125 0x00007feec9f21c67 in function_call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb7c74450, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2dc27950, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee40068830) at Objects/funcobject.c:523
#126 0x00007feec9f0bde3 in PyObject_Call (func=func@entry=0x7feeb7c74450, arg=arg@entry=0x7fee2dc27950, kw=kw@entry=0x7fee40068830) at Objects/abstract.c:2544
#127 0x00007feec9f73094 in ext_do_call (nk=0, na=0, flags=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17afa80, func=0x7feeb7c74450) at Python/ceval.c:4690
#128 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3052
#129 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feec9884db0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x7feeb7c71e90) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#130 0x00007feec9f7229d in fast_function (nk=0, na=1, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17afc48, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4471
#131 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17afc48) at Python/ceval.c:4396
#132 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#133 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feec0f1bf30, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#134 0x00007feec9f7229d in fast_function (nk=0, na=2, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17afe18, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4471
#135 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17afe18) at Python/ceval.c:4396
#136 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#137 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feec0f233b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#138 0x00007feec9f7229d in fast_function (nk=0, na=1, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17affe8, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4471
#139 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17affe8) at Python/ceval.c:4396
#140 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#141 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feec95c5cb0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0, defs=0x7feec28f7ec8, defcount=2, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#142 0x00007feec9f6ce98 in fast_function (nk=0, na=3, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17b01b8, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4471
#143 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17b01b8) at Python/ceval.c:4396
#144 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#145 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feec95c89b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=3, defs=0x7feec5d071a8, defcount=3, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#146 0x00007feec9f6ce98 in fast_function (nk=3, na=0, n=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17b0388, func=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4471
#147 call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7ffcb17b0388) at Python/ceval.c:4396
#148 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3013
#149 0x00007feec9f6c144 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7feec99a34b0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3608
#150 0x00007feec9fcb026 in PyEval_EvalCode (co=co@entry=0x7feec99a34b0, globals=globals@entry=0x7feec9a84170, locals=locals@entry=0x7feec9a84170) at Python/ceval.c:669
#151 0x00007feec9fd28cb in run_mod (mod=mod@entry=0x558201efd788, filename=filename@entry=0x7ffcb17b2dc8 "start_runner.py", globals=globals@entry=0x7feec9a84170, locals=locals@entry=0x7feec9a84170, flags=flags@entry=0x7ffcb17b05ec, arena=arena@entry=0x558201f29b90) at Python/pythonrun.c:1385
#152 0x00007feec9ef9117 in PyRun_FileExFlags (fp=0x558201f7bd10, filename=0x7ffcb17b2dc8 "start_runner.py", start=<optimized out>, globals=0x7feec9a84170, locals=0x7feec9a84170, closeit=1, flags=0x7ffcb17b05ec) at Python/pythonrun.c:1371
#153 0x00007feec9fd1db8 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags (fp=0x558201f7bd10, filename=<optimized out>, closeit=1, flags=0x7ffcb17b05ec) at Python/pythonrun.c:957
#154 0x00007feec9fd761d in Py_Main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at Modules/main.c:641
#155 0x00007feec9b1f09b in __libc_start_main (main=0x558201c49050 <main>, argc=4, argv=0x7ffcb17b0798, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffcb17b0788) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#156 0x0000558201c4908a in _start ()
```

Comment: Without describing what additional modules, configurations available to your production environment or any workload, it is obvious that this issue may not easily be replicated anywhere else.

Comment: The process runs in a container. Some additional modules that I can mention are `mongoengine` and `pymongo`. When the crash happens, the python level stacktrace has some line in one of these two libraries. The functions differ a lot in every crash. Only in gdb's trace all crashes lead to `update_refs` method. Hence, I included gdb's backtrace.

Comment: It would be useful to also provide an abbreviate version of that trace that would indicate the third-party libraries that may be at fault to save everyone's time.

Comment: I have added the trace from that involves pymongo v3.11.2. It also has other threads: periodic_executor is from pymongo. The trace involving `raven/transport/threaded.py` is from sentry client package `raven v6.10.0`. `optimizely/config_manager.py` is from `optimizely-sdk v3.4.1`.

Comment: Since nobody else has this problem it will be difficult for anyone else to replicate this to begin to debug the issue, especially if this is specific to your production server. When I was in a similar situation I would acquire the affected package source and compile those libraries with debug flags enable in an attempt to find the specific error in the C code.  Sometimes it may be the distribution's faulty binary package resulting in this segmentation fault, so it's best to compile your own packages in order to start debugging this kind of fault.

Comment: Can you post the results of **info registers** from gdb as well as a disassembly of **update_refs** ?

Comment: What I am suggesting here is that it should be possible to figure out the bug from the core you already have, and even more so, from multiple cores, but one cannot do that without access to those cores or at least information about the contents.

Comment: I have uploaded the info registers and disas of update_refs in this gist
[disas update_refs](https://gist.github.com/aswinkarthik/63deb90d750dd37787167689cf9e24a0#file-gdb-disas-update_refs) 
[info registers](https://gist.github.com/aswinkarthik/63deb90d750dd37787167689cf9e24a0#file-info-registers)